# How do you access the request body in a Spring WebFlux Webfilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

How do you access the request body in a Spring WebFlux `Webfilter`?

Say you want to build a filter that logs the request details *including the full request body* for all errors.

The `WebFilter::filter` method provides a `ServerWebExchange` that can be used to retrieve the `ServerHttpRequest` that has a `getBody` method that returns a `Flux<DataBuffer>`. Consider this non-working example:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ErrorWebFilter implements WebFilter {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    return
        chain.filter(exchange)
            .thenReturn(exchange.getResponse())
            .map(ServerHttpResponse::getStatusCode)
            .filter(HttpStatus::isError)
            .then(
                exchange.getRequest().getBody()
                    .map(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining())
                    .map(Optional::of)
                    .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty())
            )
            .doOnNext(requestBody -> {
              log.info("Error response with statusCode='{}' returned for request: {} {} with query params='{}' with body='{}'.",
                  exchange.getResponse().getRawStatusCode(),
                  exchange.getRequest().getMethod(),
                  exchange.getRequest().getPath(),
                  exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams(),
                  requestBody.orElse("")
              );
            })
            .then();

  }

}
```

In all of our tests the above does not work because `ServerHttpRequest::getBody` returns a `Mono.empty()`. And even then, I doubt that `DataBuffer::toString` is going to work.

How do we get access to the response body in a `WebFilter`?

For reference we're using SpringBoot v2.2.6, which includes Spring Framework v5.2.5.